# SQL Server : finding database disk space usage

Tags: sql-server, database

Am a newbie to SQL Server. Am trying to understand the difference between the DB disk space returned by

1. [sp_spaceused](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188776.aspx)

and the disk space indicated in

2. [the dbo.sysfiles table](http://kb.paessler.com/en/topic/18183-how-do-i-monitor-the-size-of-a-microsoft-sql-server-database)

Answer (score 0):

sp_SpaceUsed returns database size in MB.
and sys.sysfiles / sys.database_files / sys.master_files returns database size in number of 8KB pages.

If you multiply total size returned from these views with (8/1024) you will get size in MB.